# Tricky multiple where condition MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I have a table customer, a table with different criterias (These criterias are then used to make ratings). Another table has the values and its keys in it.

```
table company
==============
int company_id
varchar name
bool status

table criteria
==============
int criteria_id
varchar name
bool status


table company_criteria
==============
int company_id
int criteria_id
int criteria_value
varchar comments
```

Now i display all the criterias in the form of select boxes which will have themselves a value against each criteria (already in the DB). Now i want the user to be able to search for different companies who have those specific criteria and the stored value.

e.g: table customer has a record with id 1
table criteria has records 
1--->Reputation, 2--> Salary

table company_criteria has following records:

```
   company_id | criteria_id | criteria_value |
   ============================================
        1            1            10
        1            2            20
```

Now the user sees two select boxes (remember there are two records in the criteria table) - with different options. He selects 10 from first select box and 20 from the second select box. How would i write the Query - I tried the following

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `co`.*
 FROM (`company` co)
 JOIN `company_criteria` cc ON `co`.`company_id` = `cc`.`company_id`
 WHERE (`cc`.`criteria_id`=1 AND `cc`.`criteria_value`>=10) AND (`cc`.`criteria_id`=2 AND `cc`.`criteria_value`>=20)
```

It just doesn't work - gives me no results - always. Appreciate any help - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to put and OR instead of the AND here

```
SELECT DISTINCT `co`.*
 FROM (`company` co)
 JOIN `company_criteria` cc ON `co`.`company_id` = `cc`.`company_id`
 WHERE (`cc`.`criteria_id`=1 AND `cc`.`criteria_value`>=10) OR (`cc`.`criteria_id`=2 AND `cc`.`criteria_value`>=20)
```

between the 2 where conditions....they both cant be true at the same time I think

Comment: Thats the tricky issue here. The table company_criteria is going to have further company (id 1) records each with two records ( because of the two records in the criteria table) but with different criteria_values. i.e. A group of criteria records of a company with different values. So at least a group has to match.

Comment: Your question is unclear please tell more clearly so as to be sorted out